# why this typescript 2352 error in NuxtJs is happening?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

i'm trying to import a index.js (static data) into my index.vue and use pinia, to manage the current languag, the error says:

"Conversion from type 'number' to type '"en" | "pt"' may be an error because neither type overlaps the other sufficiently. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first."

Pinia:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export const useLangStore = defineStore("lang", {
  state: () => ({
    currentLanguage: ref<'en' | 'pt'>('pt'),
  }),

  actions: {
    toggleLanguage() {
      this.currentLanguage.value = this.currentLanguage.value === 'en' ? 'pt' : 'en';
    },
  },
});
```

Index.vue:

```
import { languageData } from "~/languages/index.js";
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from "vue";

const langStore = useLangStore();

const currentLanguage = computed(() => langStore.currentLanguage);
const currentLanguageData = computed(() => {
  const langValue = currentLanguage.value as keyof typeof languageData; (error here)
  return languageData[langValue];
});

const changeLanguage = langStore.toggleLanguage;
</script>
<Template>
# usage example
<h1>
{{ languageData[langStore.currentLanguage].about.abouttitle }}
</h1>
```

Index.js:

```
export const languageData = {
  en: {
    home: {
      homebutton: "Contact Me",
    },
    about: {
      abouttitle: "About Me",
    },
```

Comment: What specific line and column of which file is this error flagging?

Comment: i added the "(error here)" there, on index.vue (const langValue = currentLanguage.value as keyof typeof languageData; )